# Using table() function from base with dplyr pipe-syntax?

Tags: r, dplyr

I enjoy the syntax of dplyr, but I'm struggling with easily obtaining a contingency table in the same way that I can get with the base R table() function. table() is OK, but I can't figure out how to incorporate it into the dplyr pipe syntax.

Thank you for your help.

Here is some example data that has the output I'm trying to get to.

```
df <- tibble(id=c(rep("A",100),rep("B",100),rep("C",100)),
               val=c(rnorm(300,mean=500,sd=100))) %>%
  mutate(val_bin=cut(val,breaks=5))

table(df$id,df$val_bin)
```

Output:

```
    (210,325] (325,440] (440,554] (554,669] (669,784]
  A         4        22        55        18         1
  B         6        19        46        24         5
  C         3        23        44        22         8
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can `select` the columns of interest and apply the `table`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
    select(id, val_bin) %>%
    table
```

---

Or another option is to wrap within `{}`

```
df %>%
    {table(.$id, .$val_bin)}
```

---

In `tidyverse`, it is a bit more convoluted to get the required output

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
   count(id, val_bin) %>%
   pivot_wider(names_from = val_bin, values_from = n, values_fill = list(n = 0)) %>%
   column_to_rownames('id')
#   (214,338] (338,461] (461,584] (584,707] (707,831]
#A         5        30        44        20         1
#B         9        30        34        27         0
#C         8        28        43        20         1
```

Comment: Thank you! I ended up using spread() instead of pivot_wider() but get the same results.

Comment: This could be much improved by using the exposition pipe `%$%`, which was meant for this purpose. Please see answer below.

Answer (score 6):

One option is to use `with`:

```r
df %>%
  with(., table(id, val_bin))
#    val_bin
# id  (228,327] (327,426] (426,525] (525,624] (624,723]
#   A         4        19        39        22        16
#   B         5        15        41        32         7
#   C         5        14        44        25        12
```

Technically, the `.` is not required,

```r
df %>%
  with(table(id, val_bin))
```

but I find it is perhaps a little clearer in situations where it might be easy to confuse where the data is going (within `with` or `table`). (Hint: it's just about always the first function, `with` here.)

Answer (score 1):

I know the question was for a pipe `%>%`, but have you ever heard of the **exposition pipe** (`%$%`)? It’s also from the `magrittr` package (just like `%>%`) and meant exactly for what you want to do:

```r
df %$%
  table(id, val_bin)
```

Help page: https://magrittr.tidyverse.org/reference/exposition.html